# Array(SIZE).fill(1): 500x more time and 70x more memory with 10x more data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am benchmarking some simple javascript code and I see some unexpected memory usage in the following example:

```
function startTimer() {
  const time = process.hrtime();
  return time;
}

function endTimer(time) {
  function roundTo(decimalPlaces, numberToRound) {
    return +(Math.round(numberToRound + `e+${decimalPlaces}`)  + `e-${decimalPlaces}`);
  }
  const diff = process.hrtime(time);
  const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
  const result = (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]); // Result in Nanoseconds
  const elapsed = result * 0.0000010;
  return roundTo(6, elapsed); // Result in milliseconds
}

SIZE = 10000000

start = startTimer()
let a = Array(SIZE).fill(1)
elapsed = endTimer(start)

const proc = process.memoryUsage()
console.log("rss (MB): ", proc.rss/1000/1000)
console.log("heapTotal (MB): ", proc.heapTotal/1000/1000)
console.log("heapUsed (MB): ", proc.heapUsed/1000/1000)
console.log("elapsed (ms): ", elapsed)
```

When SIZE = 10MB I get:

```
[ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2:/home/jj/Documents/repos/tests_javascript]% node --max-old-space-size=4192  example.js
SIZE (MB):  10
rss (MB):  113.87
heapTotal (MB):  84.19
heapUsed (MB):  83.29
elapsed (ms):  47.44
```

When SIZE = 100MB I get 66x more rss memory and 500x longer execution time:

```
[ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2:/home/jj/Documents/repos/tests_javascript]% node --max-old-space-size=4192  example.js
SIZE (MB):  100
rss (MB):  7529.71
heapTotal (MB):  4083.26
heapUsed (MB):  4008.59
elapsed (ms):  23135.14
```

Why is this happening? How do I go about benchmarking where time/memory allocations are going?

Comment: Micro benchmarks like this are rarely very useful in Javascript.  We'd be happy to help you  solve some problem in some real code that has some specific purpose that we could offer suggestions on how to best accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm simply creating and initializing an array. This seems a quite common thing to do in a real application.

Comment: Then, you should be timing and measuring some real operation that this is part of, not trying to measure some micro benchmark that represents only a piece of something.  It's just not a productive thing to measure in Javascript.  If you measured it 10 times, you'd probably get pretty different numbers every time you ran it too.  So, it's not about whether this is a common thing to do, it's about how the interpreter optimizes code as part of a larger operation which is all that really matters.  Micro benchmarks like this just don't tell any real story.

Comment: If I ran it multiples times I get similar results. Also, this is part of a larger operation.

Comment: Would be interesting to compare this to a for-loop https://esdiscuss.org/topic/typed-array-filling-convenience-and-performance

Comment: btw unrelated to nodejs, getting same results in vanilla

Comment: i tried the same with for-loop and the js-heap is much much lower -> for 100mb its only 645MB js-Heap while fill took 4GB

Answer (score 1):

You may find this usefull:

- https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6892
- https://2ality.com/2018/12/creating-arrays.html

The performance penalty may be due the holey array type produced by the `Array(SIZE)` constructor.

After reading the above articles, you may find it interesting to compare the difference in memory and time between filling `10_000_00` and (say) `50_000_000`arrays with this ways:

```js
let a = Array(SIZE).fill(1)

let a = Array.from({ length: SIZE }).fill(1)

let a = [1]; for (let i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) a.push(1);

let a = [1]; for (let i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) a[i] = 1;

let a = new Uint8Array(SIZE).fill(1) // Wow!
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript engine optimizes on repeated use of functions. Anyway, here is another way of doing it(not fast enough but proves the just in time compiler / optimizer part):

Try producing the filled array only once, then stringify it, then use JSON.parse on string whenever you need.

```
let n=1000;

let arr=[];

for(let i=0;i<n;i++) arr.push(1);

const constant=JSON.stringify(arr);

for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
  let t = Date.now();
  let newArr = JSON.parse(constant);
  console.log(Date.now()-t);
}
```

40ms for 1m array, 450ms for 10m array.